# MySQL Attempt to create temp table with big integers fails

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a temporary table that stores the char(10) number tkey in the original table into an unsigned integer.
This fails when it encounters row 109516:

```
mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lutemp AS (SELECT cast(tkey as unsigned),ca01,ce01 FROM lu);
ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'cast(tkey as unsigned)' at row 109516
```

But if I select that row as cast to integer, it has no problem doing it:

```
mysql> select cast(tkey as unsigned) from lu limit 109515,1;


+--------------------------+
| cast(tkey as unsigned) |
+--------------------------+
|               4298001000 |

+--------------------------+
1 rows in set (0.10 sec)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont rely on the database to give you a `BIGINT` from `CAST(... UNSIGNED)`.

Max Value for UNSIGNED INT is

```
4,294,967,295
```

see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html). Your value is

```
4,298,001,000
```

Try using `BIGINT UNSIGNED` explicit:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lutemp
(SELECT tkey, ca01,ce01 FROM lu LIMIT 0);

ALTER TABLE lutemp MODIFY tkey BIGINT UNSIGNED;

INSERT INTO lutemp (tkey, ca01,ce01)
SELECT tkey, ca01,ce01 FROM lu
;
```